# Create a Redis module that accepts C code

Tags: c, gcc, redis

Is it possible to compile C code dynamically and then load it?

My goal is to create a Redis module that can accept the Redis module C code and load it dynamically as a Redis module.

It could've been easier if Redis was guaranteed to be distributed with a GCC because then I could just use `system` to call GCC, but in reality, I can't assume that GCC is available (it isn't in the official Redis docker image).

Is it somehow possible to do what I'm asking? Maybe by saving a GCC binary in memory, as a Redis key?

Comment: Any reason you focus on C code? There are couple of projects that will let you load code in different languages e.g. http://redisgears.io & https://github.com/sklivvz/cthulhu

Comment: @GuyKorland I'll check them out. My goal is to compile a C# lambda function to a Redis module, so I figured the best way to do it would be to translate the C# lambda expression tree to C, and then dynamically compile that C code and load it as a Redis module.